# MariaDB 10.1 require ssl not valid

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl, mariadb

Trying to add a user in MariaDB 10.1.22 on a centos7 server and I am getting a sql syntax error.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create user foo identified by 'password' require SSL;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'require SSL' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                           |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
| have_openssl        | YES                             |
| have_ssl            | DISABLED                        |
| ssl_ca              | /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.csr     |
| ssl_capath          |                                 |
| ssl_cert            | /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt       |
| ssl_cipher          |                                 |
| ssl_crl             |                                 |
| ssl_crlpath         |                                 |
| ssl_key             | /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key     |
| version_ssl_library | OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The CREATE USER syntax is more involved. SSL is a red herring.  `foo` is not sufficient, as pointed out here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html

Answer (score 0):

In mariadb, `SSL` is reserved word.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/

Although, I don't know yet what for.